# python 3*n + 1 - calculate longest cycle for a list of numbers

Tags: python

for a given list of numbers (input.txt) I'm trying to have an output.txt that prints out the numbers and the length of the cycle associated with each line.

So what i have till now:

1. /input.txt that looks kinda like this:

> 4 6
>
> 2 11
>
> 3 20

etc...

2. A function that calculates the length of the cycle:

> ```
> def calc_cycle(number):
> count = 1
> while number != 1:
>     if number % 2 != 0:
>         number = number * 3 + 1
>     else:
>         number = number / 2
>     count = count + 1
> return count
> ```

3. A function that calculates the maximum cycle:

> ```
> def max_cycle(n, m):
>     max_value=1
>     for i in range(n, m+1):
>         x = calc_cycle(i)
>         if max_value < x:
>             max_value = x
>     return n, m, max_value
> ```

4. And a function that reads the input.txt file and parse the values:

> ```
> def read_input(list_of_urls):
>     with open(list_of_urls) as f:
>         for line in f:
>             #n,m = [int(i) for i in line.split(' ')]
>             n,m = line.split(' ')
>             n=int(n)
>             m=int(m)
>             print n,m
> ```

Basically I'm stuck at this part, I don't see how to get an output.txt file that would look like this:

> ```
> 4 6 9  #9 being the max cycle for all the numbers between 4 and 9
> 2 11 20 #20 being the max cycle for all numbers between 2 and 11 
> 3 20 21 #21 being the max cycle for numbers between 3 and 20
> ```

Any guidance please!?

Comment: What is cycle? How do you define it?

Comment: Do you not know how to write text to a file? i'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: This is about the 3*n + 1 problem -http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36  . A cycle is how many iteration it takes for a number to get to one - see def calc_cycle

Comment: How `9` is the max cycle between `4-6` ? Your question missing some information I guess

Comment: What part of the problem are you stuck on? Are you able to generate, for example, tuples like (4,6,9), (2, 11, 20), etc.?

Comment: Instead of printing `n,m` in your `read_input` function, you basically just need to write `max_cycle(n,m)` to a new file `output.txt`.

Comment: Assuming the output examples are correct. The result from `max_cycle` seem to be correct. So i guess the problem is writing to files..

Comment: @howaboutNO - because for 4 it takes 3 iteration to get to 1 (4, 2, 1) for 5 it takes 6 iterations (5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1) and for 6 it takes 9 iterations to get to 1 (6, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1) - thus the longest cycle for the numbers between 4 and 6 is 9

Comment: @RaduAndrei I got it now.

Comment: These sequences are commonly known as [Collatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) sequences; the Wikipedia link mentions other names associated with these sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[string formating](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)

```
def read_input(list_of_urls):
    with open(list_of_urls) as f, open('output.txt', 'w+') as f2:
        for line in f:
            n,m = line.split(' ')
            n=int(n)
            m=int(m)
            _,_,thisMaxCycle = max_cycle(n,m)
            f2.write("{0} {1} {2} #{2} being the max cycle for all numbers between {0} and {1}\n".format(n,m,thisMaxCycle))
```

Comment: Nice!! I actually wasn't expecting to print anything after # , I wrote it there to be clear what is each number :)

Comment: @RaduAndrei  Just remove that part if you don't need it then :)